# How can I remove an SSH key?

Tags: git, ssh, git-svn, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I currently have an old SSH key uploaded on a server. The problem is I lost my `~/.ssh` directory (with the original `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files).

Consequently, I want to remove the old SSH key directly on the server and upload a new one.

I tried the following command without success:

```
$> ssh-add -D
```

[image]

Is there a way to completely remove an SSH key?

Comment: What with `ssh-add -d` ?

Comment: damnit, it is ssh-add -D, uppercase

Comment: Check your sockets that are being used by your ssh-agent(1).

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Note that there are at least two bug reports for `ssh-add -d/-D` *not* removing keys:

- "[Debian Bug report #472477: `ssh-add -D` does not remove SSH key from `gnome-keyring-daemon` memory](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=472477)"
- "[Ubuntu: `ssh-add -D` deleting all identities does not work. Also, why are all identities auto-added?](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/505278)"

The exact issue is:

> `ssh-add -d/-D` deletes only *manually added* keys from gnome-keyring.
> There is no way to delete automatically added keys.
> This is the original bug, and it's still definitely present.
>
> So, for example, if you have two different automatically-loaded ssh identities associated with two different GitHub accounts -- say for work and for home -- there's *no way* to switch between them. GitHubtakes the first one which matches, so you always appear as your 'home' user to GitHub, with no way to upload things to work projects.
>
> Allowing `ssh-add -d` to apply to *automatically-loaded* keys (and `ssh-add -t X` to change the lifetime of automatically-loaded keys), would restore the behavior most users expect.

---

More precisely, about the issue:

> The culprit is `gpg-keyring-daemon`:
>
> - It subverts the normal operation of ssh-agent, mostly just so that it can pop up a pretty box into which you can type the passphrase for an encrypted ssh key.
> - And it paws through your `.ssh` directory, and automatically adds any keys it finds to your agent.
> - And it won't let you delete those keys.
>
> How do we hate this? Let's not count the ways -- life's too short.
>
> The failure is compounded because newer ssh clients automatically try all the keys in your ssh-agent when connecting to a host.
> If there are too many, the server will reject the connection.
> And since gnome-keyring-daemon has decided for itself how many keys you want your ssh-agent to have, and has autoloaded them, AND WON'T LET YOU DELETE THEM, you're toast.

This bug is still confirmed in Ubuntu 14.04.4, as recently as two days ago (August 21st, 2014)

---

A possible workaround:

> - Do `ssh-add -D` to delete all your *manually* added keys. This also locks
>   the automatically added keys, but is not much use since `gnome-keyring` will ask you to unlock them anyways when you try doing a `git push`.
> - Navigate to your `~/.ssh` folder and move all your key files except the one you want to identify with into a separate folder called backup. If necessary you can also open seahorse and delete the keys from there.
> - Now you should be able to do `git push` without a problem.

---

Another workaround:

> What you really want to do is to turn off `gpg-keyring-daemon` altogether.
> Go to `System --> Preferences --> Startup Applications`, and unselect the "`SSH Key Agent (Gnome Keyring SSH Agent)`" box -- you'll need to scroll down to find it.
>
> You'll still get an `ssh-agent`, only now it will behave sanely: no keys autoloaded, you run ssh-add to add them, and if you want to delete keys, you can. Imagine that.

[This comments](https://superuser.com/questions/281217/cant-remove-keys-from-ssh-agent-even-rebooting-doesnt-help#comment739325_301444) actually suggests:

> The solution is to keep `gnome-keyring-manager` from ever starting up, which was strangely difficult by finally achieved by removing the program file's execute permission.

---

[Ryan Lue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4865822/ryan-lue) adds another interesting corner case [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464930/how-to-remove-an-ssh-key/25465155?noredirect=1#comment106007588_25465155):

> In case this helps anyone: I even tried deleting the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files altogether, and the key was still showing up.
>
> Turns out **`gpg-agent` was caching them in a `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol` file**; I had to manually delete them from there.

That is the case when [the **`keygrip`**](https://incenp.org/notes/2015/gnupg-for-ssh-authentication.html) has been added [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48922829/6309).

Comment: Another option in Ubuntu 14-16 is to use the gui 'Passwords and keys' (you can seach for ssh to find it) .  Choose which eg OpenSS keys, then right click on the key and choose delete.  You may need to restart your system to see it that it's removed.

Comment: Why is this info about the `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` the selected answer? The original poster said he wants to `remove the old SSH key directly on the server and upload a new one`. That sounds like he wants to edit `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote host.

Comment: @H2ONaCl I agree `ssh-add -D` and `authorized_keys` are two different operations/items, as illustrated in http://askubuntu.com/a/490107/5470. But the question was centered around the inability to remove that (passphrase-protected) key from the ssh agent. I suppose the `authorized_keys` update part was done independently.

Comment: @VonC, by the way, to remove the keys on the client host, optionally do this: `ssh-add -l` and count how many keys there are perhaps by piping to `wc`. Then `rm ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` Then optionally do this:`ssh-add -l` and you will see there is a different count. In other words, deletion from the agent is automatic if you delete from the file system.

Comment: @user3257693 that deletes the key from disk - when one wants to delete a key from one's agent, one does not want to throw away the key forever!

Comment: This answer lead me to solve a problem showing up with ssh forwarding enabled. Going from an Ubuntu 16.04 machine to a debian system where all ssh credentials are being forwarded a `git clone` was using the first key in the chain instead of the version in the config file on the Ubuntu box. The bad key was getting sucked in automatically and forwarded to the Debian box.

Comment: Just got bit by this bug on  Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks a lot for this answer!

Comment: This is a real pain in the rear. I'm working on company projects and contracted to work under another company. This just adds wasted time to managing both. I hope a fix comes soon!

Comment: In case this helps anyone: I even tried deleting the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files altogether, and the key was _still_ showing up. Turns out gpg-agent was caching them in a `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol` file; I had to manually delete them from there.

Comment: @RyanLue Thank you. Very interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: for ` if you have two different automatically-loaded ssh identities associated with two different GitHub accounts -- say for work and for home -- there's no way to switch between them. GitHubtakes the first one which matches, so you always appear as your 'home' user to GitHub, with no way to upload things to work projects.` , I set `IdentitiesOnly`  to true in my ~/.ssh/config TO  ingoring the ssh-agent

Comment: @L.T Switch between them from within one repository? Because for multiple repos, I always use `~/.ssh/config` entry, which allows me to reference the exact key I want.

Comment: you #@$@!#!  i ruined all my keys by running -D .

Comment: @SimpleFellow Can you add those keys back to the agent? I mean `-D` does not delete the actual key file, right?

Answer (score 27):

Before Remove Identity You need to start `ssh-agent` with this command

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

For Remove All Identity

```
ssh-add -D
```

To Remove Specific Identity

```
ssh-add -d ~/.ssh/sshkeynamewithout.pub
```

For Find a List of available Identify by using this command

```
ssh-add -l
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove a specific key listed by `ssh-add -l` *without* referencing it by filename? I have a Yubikey from which SSH keys are added to the agent via `ssh-add -K`, hence their don't exist any files within the `.ssh/` directory.

Comment: worked ssh-add -d ~/.ssh/sshkeynamewithout.pub

Answer (score 21):

If you're trying to perform an SSH-related operation and get the following error:

```
$ git fetch
no such identity: <ssh key path>: No such file or directory
```

You can remove the missing SSH key from your SSH agent with the following:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`  # start ssh agent
$ ssh-add -D <ssh key path>  # delete ssh key
```

Answer (score 19):

**Check if folder *.ssh* is on your system**

1. Go to folder --> /Users/administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub

**If not, then**

2. Open Terminal.

**Paste in the terminal**

3. Check user → ssh -T git@gitlab.com

**Remove existing SSH keys**

4. Remove existing SSH keys → `rm ~/.ssh/github_rsa.pub`

**Create New**

5. Create new SSH key → `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`
6. **The public key has been saved in** "/Users/administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub."
7. **Open the public key saved path.**
8. **Copy the SSH key** → GitLab Account → Setting → SSH Key → Add key
9. **Test again from the terminal** → `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`

Comment: What if ssh-key is used to connect to remote servers and removing and generating a new key is not an option?

Answer (score 9):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, you lost your `.ssh` directory containing your private key on your local machine and so you want to remove the public key which was on a server and which allowed key-based login.

In that case, it will be stored in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file in your home directory on the server. You can just edit this file with a text editor and delete the relevant line if you can identify it (even easier if it's the only entry!).

I hope that key wasn't your only method of access to the server and you have some other way of logging in and editing the file. You can either manually add a new public key to `authorised_keys` file or use `ssh-copy-id`. Either way, you'll need password authentication set up for your account on the server, or some other identity or access method to get to the `authorized_keys` file on the server.

`ssh-add` adds identities to your SSH agent which handles management of your identities locally and "the connection to the agent is forwarded over SSH remote logins, and the user can thus use the privileges given by the identities anywhere in the network in a secure way." (man page), so I don't think it's what you want in this case. It doesn't have any way to get your public key onto a server without you having access to said server via an SSH login as far as I know.

Comment: I deleted this file and I can still connect. So it definitely was not contained in here...
It was an automatically added key but still doesn't exist anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

I opened "Passwords and Keys" application in my Unity and removed unwanted keys from *Secure Keys* -> *OpenSSH keys*
And they automatically had been removed from *ssh-agent -l* as well.

Comment: Beware that this also deletes them from the directory `~/.ssh`

Comment: What is "Unity" (in this context)? The term "Unity" is heavily overloaded. [Ubuntu Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Unity) or [Ubuntu's Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface))? Or something else?

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this bug is still present in [Ubuntu 19.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.04_(Disco_Dingo)) (Disco Dingo). The workaround [suggested by VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464930/how-can-i-remove-an-ssh-key/25465155#25465155) worked perfectly, summarizing for my version:

- Click on Activities tab on top left corner
- On the search box that comes up, begin typing "startup applications"
- Click on the "Startup Applications" icon
- On the box that pops up, select the gnome key ring manager application (can't remember the exact name on the GUI but it is distinctive enough) and remove it.

Next, I tried `ssh-add -D` again, and after reboot `ssh-add -l` told me *The agent has no identities.* I confirmed that I still had the `ssh-agent` daemon running with `ps aux | grep agent`. So I added the key I most frequently used with GitHub (`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`) and all was good!

Now I can do the normal operations with my most frequently used repository, and if I occasionally require access to the other repository which uses the RSA key, I just dedicate one terminal for it with `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"`. Solved! Credit goes to VonC for pointing out the bug and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu, if your current ssh-agent already loaded some keys, I found there is no way to remove it.

You have to kill the current ssh-agent by `eval "$(ssh-agent -k)"`

Then, start a new ssh-agent by `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

Ok, now you are free to add a preferred key like `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_preferred_key`

Comment: This workaround is simpler than most mentioned here. But you don't need to kill the current ssh-agent. You can just start a new agent, and it will have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me ([openSUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) Leap 42.3, [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Software_Compilation)) was to rename the folder `~/.gnupg` which apparently contained the cached keys and profiles.

After KDE logout/logon the ssh-add/agent is running again and the folder is created from scratch, but the old keys are all gone.

I didn't have success with the other approaches.