# I want git to ask me everytime for username and password when I push/pull

Tags: git

I just want to **disable git from using publickey entirely** and **start asking me for username and password everytime I push and pull**.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Why? Public key auth is more secure over SSH.

Comment: I know. I can't explain a 50 year old how to generate a public/private key in windows, then upload it into git, and then fail when the user will go to another machine where there will not be this key. I just need to use a git in my local network without all this public/private key thing

Comment: How are you setting up your remotes? I had the opposite problem , it always asked me for u/p every time and it took me a while to figure out how to change that.

Comment: If your user doesn't *have* a public key, Git will ask every time, no? Are you the admin for their remote?

Answer (score 1):

You can have Git store your credentials permanently using the following in your laptop:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

If you want Git to resume to asking you for credentials every time it needs to connect to the remote repository, you can run this command:

```
git config --unset credential.helper
```

Answer (score 0):

Its enough to remove ssh key.  Comprehend description can be found here: [How to remove a ssh key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464930/how-to-remove-a-ssh-key)

Comment: I have no key to remove. I wish I can just tell git to ignore the whole keys auth altogether and just use username and password. Just like ftp.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit (by @tarikmanoar as suggested by moderators and comments)*

**WARNING: If you use `credential.helper store` from the answer, your password is going to be stored completely unencrypted ("as is") at `~/.git-credentials`. Please consult the comments section below or the answers from the "Linked" section, especially if your employer has zero-tolerance for security issues.**

Even though accepted, it doesn't answer the actual OP's question about omitting a username only (no password). For the readers with that exact problem @grawity's [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/847181/skip-username-prompt-when-using-git) might come in handy.

---

**Original answer (by @Alexander Zhu):**

You can store your credentials using the following command

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
Username: <type your username>
Password: <type your password>
```

Also, I suggest you read
[`$ git help credentials`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)