# Github Grief - Getting keys from where?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have 2 different GitHub accounts and I am running Ubuntu.

I was following answers on Stack Overflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig) and was getting all kinds of grief with the wrong key being used. Trying to narrow down the problem ...

- I deleted all the keys in `~/.ssh` - still getting the wrong user when pushing to Github.
- I deleted the `known_hosts` and `config` files in `~/.ssh`. - the same as above.
- I deleted all the keys in both GitHub accounts - I can still git push!
- I rebooted my system - but I still can push to Github!?!

Where are these keys now stored? Depending what I place in my local `.git/config` I can get the GitHub account I want, but am mighty curious about where and how these keys get checked! I would have figured that doing a `git push` now would fail.

Edit: I can commit to the Github I want - I used "none" for global git config email and set the local git config to the email I want to commit under.

I spun up another partition (different Ubuntu version) on my same machine - did a git clone, and can commit! Didn't ask for my ssh key - just my github user/pass. There is no ssh key on my github account at the moment. Somehow it still remembers, I'll just accept that.

Comment: Try running `ssh-add -l` to list any keys currently known by your ssh agent. It may be caching something, or pulling a key from some place you are not aware of. Also, since you are using Ubuntu, check out this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464930/how-to-remove-a-ssh-key

Comment: I did that, listed them.  Then I also removed them from ssh agent, as I had the same thought. Still not what being committed as I want. That is when I deleted and I was surprised that it worked! I spun up another partition (Ubuntu14) that I boot from (same machine) and it still works!?!

Comment: Is your remote URL (`git remote -v`) showing a git or ssh URL? Or is it https? Your ssh configuration won't apply if you've used the wrong URL when cloning.